# Analysis of Metric Properties in an Infinite Set with Discrete Metric

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

I am not sure if my solution to the following problem is correct

1. Let x be an infinite set. for x $\in$ X and y $\in$ X we define:
   \begin{equation}
   d(x,y) = \left\{
   \begin{array}{ll}
         1 & x \neq y \\
         0 & x=y
   \end{array} 
   \right. 
   \end{equation}
   Prove that d is metric, Which subsets of X are open which are closed? which are compact?

My answer

I show that the function $d: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defines a metric on the set $X$, where $X$ is an infinite set.

1. **Non-negativity:**

For any $x, y \in X$, $d(x, y)$ is either 0 or 1, which are both non-negative.

2. **Identity:**

$d(x, x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 1 & x \neq x \\ 0 & x = x \end{array} \right\} = 0$ for all $x \in X$ due to the definition.

3. **Symmetry:**

$d(x, y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 1 & x \neq y \\ 0 & x = y \end{array} \right\} = d(y, x)$ whenever $x \neq y$.

4. **Triangle Inequality:**

Suppose $x, y, z \in X$. We need to show that $d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z)$.

- Case 1: $x \neq y$ and $y \neq z$

In this case, $d(x, y) = d(y, z) = 1$.  Therefore, $d(x, z) = 1 \leq 1 + 1 = d(x, y) + d(y, z)$.

- Case 2: $x = z$

Then $d(x, z) = 0$.  The triangle inequality still holds: $0 \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z)$ (since all terms are non-negative).

Therefore, d satisfies all four properties of a metric.

**Open Sets:**

In this metric, all sets are open.  Consider any point $x \in X$. The open ball centered at $x$ with radius $\varepsilon > 0$ is defined as:

$B_{\varepsilon}(x) = \{y \in X \mid d(x, y) < \varepsilon\}$

Since the metric only takes values 0 and 1, any $\varepsilon > 0$ will result in an empty set $B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ but the definition of open sets only requires that every point in the set be an interior point.  Since any point in $X$ is its own interior point all sets qualify as open in this metric.

**Closed Sets:**

Since the complement of any open set (which are all sets in this case) is closed, all sets are also closed.

**Compact Sets:**

A set is compact in a metric space if it's totally bounded and complete in this space, total boundedness is not possible for any given finite covering by balls centered at points in $X$, we can always add another element to $X$ that wouldn't be covered by any existing ball.  Since compactness requires total boundedness, no sets are compact in this metric space.

So

- d is a metric on X.
- All subsets of X are both open and closed.
- No subsets of X are compact.

Answer (score 1):

Some corrections:

For any $0<\varepsilon\leq1$ and $x\in X$ we will have $B(x,\varepsilon)=\{x\}$, as $d(x,x)=0<\varepsilon$.

For $\varepsilon>1$ we have $B(x,\varepsilon)=X$, as every element is at most at distance $1$ from $x$.

From here, every set is open (since every element is by itself a ball) and thus every set is closed.

With respect to compactness, every finite subset will be compact (as in every other topological space) since from every open cover we may take an open set per element.

Nonetheless, any infinite subset $A$ will not be compact: one may not find a finite subcover from $\{\{a\}: a\in A\}$.